# update database,not add same username in list again

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $update_list = "";
foreach($keys as $k)
{
    if(!isset($_GET[$k]) || empty($_GET[$k]))
    {
        exit("error");
    }

    $update_list .= ($k != "username") ? "{$k}={$_GET[$k]},":"";
}
$update_list = substr($update_list, 0, -1);

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=highscores", "root", "");
$row_list = implode(",", $keys);
$question_marks = substr(str_repeat("?,", sizeof($keys)), 0, -1);

$query = "INSERT INTO `highscores` ({$row_list}) VALUES ({$question_marks}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {$update_list}";
```

When i logout it will add an another username with same name into the list.
What i wan't is that when a user logs out it will update the stats and not create a same username with the updated stats into the list.
What is wrong here.

mvg.

Comment: Why did you tag this with the Java tag?

Comment: Please describe the table you are trying to work with.  If the primary key is autoincrement, you will never update as the duplicate key will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query should not be INSERT INTO but UPDATE try writing something like:

```
$query = "UPDATE `highscores`SET({$question_marks}) WHERE username=usernameToUpdate";
```

replace the 'usernameToUpdate' to the username related to the 'highscore' you want to change. It's probably better to use 'userId' instead of username but it can done either way,

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you haven't actually set up a primary key in the database.  `ON DUPLICATE KEY` will only trigger if you have a unique key defined. All primary keys are unique.

Every table should have a primary key. While it's technically not required,  if you want your queries to not have awful performance, then you need to have a primary key.

If I am wrong and you do have a primary key set up, try setting up a unique index on username.  That should fix your problem.

Comment: The key is on the numbers, not on the usernames, think thats it.?

Comment: Add a unique index (key) on usernames (doesn't have to be a primary key, just unique) and I'm almost certain it will fix this issue.